# Google Sheets most frequent and just one value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, matching

I'm trying to count the number of most frequent text in a column, I have this formula that I used before in excel...

```
=INDEX(E9:E18,MODE(IF((E9:E18<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(E9:E18,$B$1:$B1,0)),MATCH(E9:E18,E9:E18,0))))
```

This works, but when I get some repited value shows `#N/A`
Here is an capture from this I would like to know how can I resolve this I tried with

```
=INDEX(E9:E18,MODE(IF(AND(E9:E18<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(E9:E18,$B$1:$B1,0)),MATCH(E9:E18,E9:E18,0))))
```

But I get lost trying to put a condition like `only one value = value`
Some help or code that I could use?

[image]

So this is my problem [image]

Comment: Have you tried COUNTA() ?

Comment: Your screen shot is of Google Sheets.  Are you sure you want an Excel answer?  What works in Excel does not always work in Google Sheets.

Comment: Why did you add the `AND()`?  `AND()` does not work with array formula.

Comment: What about `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: @SolarMike COUNTA not working because it counts also some cells that have a formula that gives me some values like `""`.

@ScottCraner your are right I changed the description and this formula works in the same way that Excel. Also the AND() was something that I tried but I didn't know how to add the condition.

@Dominique COUNTIF() YOU HAVE SOME EXAMPLE?

Answer (score 1):

*With Office 365:
=INDEX( SORTBY(UNIQUE(A1:A10), COUNTIF( A1:A10, UNIQUE(A1:A10) ),-1), 1 )*

Oops - i just saw the Google sheets edit.

For most frequent:

```
=INDEX( SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A10), COUNTIF( A1:A10, UNIQUE(A1:A10) ),0), 1 )
```

For Just One Value:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A1:A10),COUNTIF(A1:A10,UNIQUE(A1:A10))=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually this is really close what I want but I need as an example if K is the most frequent show me the K insted the 3 and if is only one value K give me the K. My problem exactly is that give me an error that any of the values occur more than once.

Comment: @Eduardomaker - the answer is in C2 - i just put the table on the side to show the counts so as to check that it C2 is correct.

Comment: I used your formula and result not in the correct way
`=INDEX( SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A10), COUNTIF( A1:A10, UNIQUE(A1:A10) ),-1), 1 )`

Comment: ok- for Just One Value, use: `=FILTER(UNIQUE(A1:A10),COUNTIF(A1:A10,UNIQUE(A1:A10))=1)` and it will spill all of the values that only occur once.

Comment: Sorry, to be so problematic, but with that formula I receive this error: 
`Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in K7.`

I'm using this formula `=FILTER(UNIQUE(K2:K5),COUNTIF(K2:K5,UNIQUE(K2:K5))=1)`

Comment: actually now I realize that I don't want two formulas I want one doing both cases, actually I used this formula that you put me for most frequent but gives me the just one value actually both formulas that you put give me the same result

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:A}; 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use it sorry

Comment: @Eduardomaker copy it and paste it

Comment: I try it but I'm using Google sheets

Comment: @Eduardomaker yes, this is for google sheets